# Format MySql time for display to client, undefined offset error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that is supposed to calculate how long ago an article was written and then return whatever value it has got when it is called. However I get the notice message which is an error I dnt want to supress but solve.

```
function getTimeAgo($date,$granularity=1){

    $values = explode(" ",$date);
    $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));//GET CURRENT UTC TIME
    $date = $values[2] . "-" . $values[1] . "-" . $values[5] . " " . $values[3];    
    $difference = strtotime($time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($date);
    $retval='';
    $periods = array('decade' => 315360000,
    'year' => 31536000,
    'month' => 2628000,
    'week' => 604800, 
    'day' => 86400,
    'hour' => 3600,
    'min' => 60,
    'sec' => 1);

    foreach ($periods as $key => $value) {
    if ($difference >= $value) {
        $time = floor($difference/$value);
        $difference %= $value;
        $retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';
        $retval .= (($time > 1) ? $key.'s' : $key);
        $granularity--;
    }
    if ($granularity == '0') { break; }
    }
    return $retval.' ago';
}
```

}

ERROR: is that there is an undefined offset [2] , [1], [5] and [3] at this particular location

```
$date = $values[2] . "-" . $values[1] . "-" . $values[5] . " " .
```

Comment: What you get for $date before explode ?

Comment: After exploding the $date variable, do a `print_r()` on it to see what the array contains. It would seem that you are passing an incorrect `$date` value.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty $date before explode is in this format 2013-12-01 08:16:32

Comment: @PhilCross, the date passed to the function is in the above format i.e 0000-00-00 00:00:00 , before the explode() is called

Comment: And output you desire on $date = $values[2] . "-" . $values[1] . "-" . $values[5] . " " . ?

Comment: If date is in 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format, then you will get only 2 values in array. So you can't access 5, 2

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I desire to get something like "2 days ago", "1 year ago" e.t.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function accepts  $date value as  2013-12-01 08:16:32

so doing

```
$values = explode(" ",$date);
```

will give you array as

```
$values[0] = 2013-12-01
$values[1] = 08:16:32
```

So

```
$date = $values[2] . "-" . $values[1] . "-" . $values[5] . " "
```

will not have indexes 2,5....

In case the function receives an empty data, then doing explode will return all invalid index.

You can use the $date from the argument directly inside

```
$difference = strtotime($time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($date);
```

if the passed value is in the format 2013-12-01 08:16:32